# Reusing relationship from SQLAlchemy model in a subquery model (mapper error)

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to programmatically create subclasses of a Flask-SQLAlchemy model that only contain a subset of columns and relationship.

In the metaclass, I am copying the relationship I want to keep from `ParentModel.__mapper__.relationships["some_relationship"]`.

The following is a streamlined minimal version of that code:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

class Bar(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("bar.id"))
    bar = db.relationship(Bar, backref='foos')
    
class FooViewMeta(type(db.Model)):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["__table__"] = (select(Foo)
                        .with_only_columns(Foo.id, Foo.bar_id, Foo.bar)
                        .subquery())
        attrs["bar"] = Foo.__mapper__.relationships["bar"]
        attrs["__mapper_args__"] = {"exclude_properties": ["bar"]}
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, (db.Model,), attrs)

class FooView(metaclass=FooViewMeta):
    pass
```

Passing `{"exclude_properties": ["bar"]}` silences a warning on property conflict between `Foo` and `Bar`.

However, when trying to use the relationship from the original model:

```
q = Foo.query.options(joinedload(Foo.bar),)
q.first()
```

I get the following cryptic error, which seems to indicate that SQLAlchemy got confused on which class to use for the `bar` relationship:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError'>: Mapped class Mapper[FooView(anon_1)] does 
not apply to any of the root entities in this query, e.g. Mapper[Foo(foo)]. 
Please specify the full path from one of the root entities to the target attribute.
```

Is there a way I can (programmatically) create `FooView` with the same `bar` relationship as `Foo`, without breaking the mapper?